# Index of international economic cooperation

Tags: international-trade

What metric captures the historic level of economic cooperation between countries? Something that would capture:

1. USA outsourcing its manufacturing to China (positive).
2. Creation/expansion of European Union (positive).
3. Brexit (negative).
4. Covid lockdowns (negative).
5. Trump and tariffs (negative).
6. Protectionsim of 1930s (negative).
7. World Wars (negative)

Thanks!

Comment: If this is about trade in goods and services, then measuring this as a percentage of world GDP is a possible indicator (though things can go wrong if countries unite or split, and different population growth can also be a factor)  E.g. https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NE.TRD.GNFS.ZS

Comment: @Henry, I literally just stumbled up this as well whilst browsing through the "Our World in Data", it is called the Openness index. Pretty neat.

Comment: For individual countries, it is more complicated as larger countries tend to have a smaller number since they can sell to themselves